# Connect Sublime Text 3 with FTP and show folder structure via fixed user interface

Tags: editor, sublimetext3

I'm using Sublime Text 3 with the SFTP package. This package is working good so far, but I want to have a fixed sidebar which shows me the folder structure for the server I'm connected to via FTP.

Currently it looks like this

[image: Sublime Text 3 SFTP Package]

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Sublime provides no API for a plugin to modify the contents of the Sidebar in any way, but you may want to read: https://wbond.net/sublime_packages/sftp/sidebar

Answer (score -1):

You can use Visual Studio, here is a tutorial for remote developing, you can see the folder structure on the side as well. Took me quite a while to find this, works great!

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QW70p8lLE4A

Comment: Visual Studio is a so weight application, it can't be a solution if the need is only to browse remote files via ftp.